# no request to minify javascripts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

MVC4 C# web site, running in debug mode, the code in "BundleConfig" file is has:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js", 
                "~/Scripts/jquery.simplemodal.js", 
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js", 
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js", 
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js", 
                "~/Scripts/site.js", 
                "~/Scripts/jquery.watermark.js", 
                "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.min.js" ,
                "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"
```

In web.config, `debug="true"`

I open firebug and see that in the "net -> js" tab section, only calls to not minify js is being made. All minify js files are not being requested from the client.

In my layout my code is:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
```

The problem started after I installed the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.1.0.0" package from nuget... when I run the web site in release mode all working good.
I don't have the not minify js files and I want to continue working in Debug mode. How can I fix it ? Why no request to minify js from client occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Bundling and Minification in debug mode, bundling/minification is disabled.

You can override this and force bundling and minification by adding `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` to your `RegisterBundles`.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //your bundle code
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Seeing your comment it seems I misunderstood your question.

When you are in debug mode and `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false`, the `.min` version of files are **NOT** used. Instead, the **full debug version** of the files will be used. So your scripts folder should have BOTH versions of the files: like

```
jquery-1.9.1.min.js 
jquery-1.9.1.js
```

In debug mode, `jquery-1.9.1.js` will be used. In release mode, `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` will be used.

If you only have one version of the file, then just remove the ".min" from the file name.

Comment: this will cause all files to be minified ... I want to be able to see other files in firebug as well.

Comment: but I have some files only in "min" version. I want them to be served in debug mode as well. it was working until I downloaded display modes package from nuget to make my site work on mobile.

Comment: @HaddarMacdasi I updated my answer. Hopefully this clarifies things.